# the mechanic beneath combobox with same datasource

Tags: c#, winforms

I have notice that when two combobox share the same datasource( for example  a `DataTable`),they will share the same selected index.

I would like to know how this behaviour is implemented.

It feels like that `DataTable` has fire some sort of event when a 'current row' or 'active row' have change, and the comboboxs that bind to it capture the event and make coresponding changes. However, I saw that event when you use datasource like `List`, it works too.

Actually I would like to make a RadioButton to update synchronously with the two combobox, how should I implement that?

Questions I saw on the web mainly deal with how to de-synchronize the combobox with same datasource,like this [Multiple Combo Boxes With The Same Data Source (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344366/multiple-combo-boxes-with-the-same-data-source-c), and this [Binding two combo boxes to the same data source,that each combo will have individual behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185560/binding-two-combo-boxes-to-the-same-data-source-that-each-combo-will-have-indivi), [Share ComboBox DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861520/share-combobox-datasource).

Comment: Looking at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886653/comboboxes-are-linked-for-some-reason) I guess you would also use a common BindingSource (if that can indeed be bound to a RadioButton?!)

Comment: @TaW I know how to de-couple the common datasource problem. Here I just want to know how coupling of two comboboxs happend, so I could take advantage of the machanic. No, bindingsource cannot bind to radiobutton.

Comment: I know you knew, I just want to point out how the coupling is done in the Comboboxes. If you can't do it the same way for the RadioButton, I guess you will have to find some event driven method.. [`Bindingsource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has a `PositionChanged` event..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is implemented by the [BindingContext Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The crucial part is:

> For each data source on a Windows Form, there is a single CurrencyManager or PropertyManager.

If you set a `ComboBox`'s (or `ListControl`'s) datasource,  it registers itself to the containing `Control`'s `BindingContext` so it will communicate with its `CurrencyManager`. When two `ListControl`s register with the same data source, they receive the same `CurrencyManager`.

You can simply check this by

```
this.comboBox1.BindingContext[lst].CurrentChanged += Form1_CurrentChanged;
this.comboBox2.BindingContext[lst].CurrentChanged += Form1_CurrentChanged;
this.BindingContext[lst].CurrentChanged += Form1_CurrentChanged;

void Form1_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(((CurrencyManager)sender).GetHashCode());
}
```

This will show three identical hashcodes in the output window if you change the selected item of *one* combo box.

This also shows why there is no "shortcut" to a `RadioButton`'s value, because it doesn't communicate with the `CurrencyManager` (it's not a `ListControl`). You'll have to write code to sync its value with a combo box's current value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

- Create a `BindingSource` which you can use as the **common** `DataSource` for **both** `ComboBoxes`. So they still are coupled, but to a normal `BindingSource`, not the hidden default one: `myBS = new BindingSource(myDT, myDT.Columns[myColumn].ColumnName);`
- Add an event for changes in the `Position`:  `myBS .PositionChanged += myBS_PositionChanged;`
- Put code in the event to control the values of the `RadioButton`..

The logic in the event code is up to you; here is an example:

```
void myBS_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   radioButton1.Checked = myBS.Current.ToString() == "2";
}
```